# Nested records using join Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have these models

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :car_locations ,:dependent=>:destroy
  has_many :rides,:dependent=>:destroy
end

class CarLocation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :car
end

class Ride < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :car
end
```

There is a **`status`** attribute in `Ride` Model of `boolean` type.

Now I want those `CarLocation`s whose car rides status is `false` or don't have any car ride with in minimum complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want those Car Locations whose car rides `status` is `false`

```
CarLocation.joins(car: :rides).where(rides: { status: false })
```

> or don't have any car ride

```
CarLocation.includes(car: :rides)
           .where(rides: { id: nil })
           .references(:rides)
```

Combining both together:

```
CarLocation.includes(car: :rides)
           .where('rides.status = false OR rides.id IS NULL')
           .references(:rides)
```

Comment: This cause error :
> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "rides"
LINE 1: ...ECT "car_locations".* FROM "car_locations" WHERE (rides.stat...

Comment: @JaiKumarRajput according to your description in OP this is impossible. I mean, this should work with the set up you've shown

Comment: if I replace includes with joins then this works perfect. but using includes...  facing error. Please correct me if I'm doing somthing wrong

Comment: @JaiKumarRajput hm... This is strange because it should all work. Can you insert the whole error?

Comment: `CarLocation.includes(car: :rides).where('rides.status = false OR rides.id IS NULL').references(:rides)` - does this work ?

Comment: 2.3.0 :059 >   CarLocation.includes([car: :rides]).where('rides.paid = false OR rides.id IS NULL')
  CarLocation Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "car_locations".* FROM "car_locations" WHERE (rides.paid = false OR rides.id IS NULL)
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "rides"
LINE 1: ...ECT "car_locations".* FROM "car_locations" WHERE (rides.paid...
                                                             ^

Comment: @dp7 super nice catch! Thanks! I'm on Rails5 and did not have to use `references` (worked without it)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko I'm also on Rails 5 :(

Comment: @JaiKumarRajput again - strange :) Anyway, I edited the answer with `references` part

Comment: Thanks 
 both of you guys :)